# Unable to Automatically step into Server, verify Symbols are loaded..generic list

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, c#-4.0

In VS2010 I call several various Methods within the Web Service from the Presentation layer and I can step into them all, except the one which passes a an Array from the presentation layer into the web service like so:

```
bool result = ws.AddGroup(txtNewMaster.ToString(), Minors.ToArray());
```

Web Method

```
[WebMethod]
public bool AddGroup(string majorOperator, List < string > minors)
```

I've tried cleaning the solution, and I've trawled the net but can't find anything specific to just one Web Method causing this issue.

Comment: I think it maybe to do with only being allowed to do debugging on  Primitive data types between web services, but there must be a workaround....

Answer (score 3):

Ok, Couldn't get it to work, but managed a work around, I put the breakpoint on the next instruction in the Web Method and set my Start Up Projects in the solution as Multiple Start up projects, hope this helps someone else.